# Method Name Expected Error- C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

About the code:

I am making a windows form Application for TIC TAC TOE game. This is one of the methods in it. It checks for the winner diagonally,horizontally,vertically.

Error:

In right hand side of the && statement, i get an error saying "Method name expected". I am not able to figure out the error. I hope someone could help.

```
        private void checkForwinner()
        {
        bool there_is_a_winner= false;

        //horizontal check
        if((A1.Text==A2.Text)&& (A2.Text==A3.Text)(!A1.Enabled))
        there_is_a_winner=true;

        else if((B1.Text==B2.Text)&& (B2.Text==B3.Text)(!A2.Enabled))
        there_is_a_winner=true;

        else if ((C1.Text == C2.Text) && (C2.Text == C3.Text)(!A3.Enabled))
            there_is_a_winner = true;

        //Vertical Check
        else if ((A1.Text == B1.Text) && (B1.Text == C1.Text)(!A1.Enabled))
            there_is_a_winner = true;

        else if ((A2.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == C2.Text)(!B1.Enabled))
            there_is_a_winner = true;

        else if ((A3.Text == B3.Text) && (B3.Text == C3.Text)(!C1.Enabled))
            there_is_a_winner = true;

        //Diagonal Check
        else if ((A1.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == C3.Text)(!A1.Enabled))
            there_is_a_winner = true;

        else if ((A3.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == C1.Text)(!C1.Enabled))
            there_is_a_winner = true;
        }
```

Comment: What does `(A2.Text==A3.Text)(!A1.Enabled)` mean? That's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing && in every if statement.

Also, always give a space before apllying `&&` operator. Try making your code easier to read.

```
if((A1.Text==A2.Text) && (A2.Text==A3.Text)(!A1.Enabled))
        there_is_a_winner=true;
```

Use

```
if((A1.Text==A2.Text) && (A2.Text==A3.Text) && (!A1.Enabled))
        there_is_a_winner=true;
```

Similarly, do in all if-else statements.